# MS Project with error TF82039

Tags: ms-project-server-2010

I've already searched for this case but I cannot find any solution to solve it.

currently, I use MS Project 2010, connect to TFS 2010. Yesterday, It still connected successfully. But today, I have the error:
"TF82039: Team Foundation was unable to modify the project plan."

Here are my steps to connect to TFS:

1. Create new 1 blank Project.
2. At team tab, click "Choose team project"
3. Choose 1 team project.
4. Click Connect -> appear 1 popup with above error message.

Please help me to solve this error.

Thank a lot.

Comment: I found some useful info here, but I'm not sure if this is your case. However, there is more info here that you use to provide and help someone solve your problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/4015dbfe-64c7-4d22-aa3f-612bc9b3367c